# How can I trigger an event after two different buttons have been clicked?

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a game. In this particular level, the screen is full of buttons, and you have to press two specific buttons in order to move on to the next level. So far, I've tried using a counter (set a variable, add +1 each time the right button is clicked, and then move to the next level when that variable reaches 2), playing with .val(), and having correct button clicks return "true" values (so when two "true" values are received it moves on to the next level". None of these have worked, and to be honest, I don't understand .val() that well. Also, I don't know if this would affect it, but I disable each correct button after it has been clicked.

I've already checked out this page, but I'm not sure if I entirely understand it. It seems like it's doing the same thing I attempted earlier, adding 1 to a variable upon a button click and triggering the event when the variable reached 2: [How to trigger an event after clicking two different button in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415344/how-to-trigger-an-event-after-clicking-two-different-button-in-javascript)

TL;DR: Does anybody know how to trigger an event after *two* buttons have both been clicked?

```
//first button
$("#button").click(function() {
    $(this).prop("disabled", true);
});

//second button
$("#otherButton").click(function() {
    $(this).prop("disabled", true);
});

//then, after the above two buttons have been pressed, i want to hide Level 2 (.lvl2) and show Level 3 (.lvl3).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store a global variable and update it to true after clicking on the first button. When clicking the second button, check if that variable is set to true. If it is, move to the next level.

```js
$(function(){
  var firstClicked;
//first button
$("#button").click(function() {
    firstClicked = true;
});

//second button
$("#otherButton").click(function() {
    if(firstClicked) {
        $('#level').text('Next Level');
    }
});
});
```

```css
#button, #otherButton {
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    background-color: #58d;
    width: 50px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#level {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="button">First</span>
<span id="otherButton">Second</span>
<div id="level"></div>
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you! Do you know how to modify it so that if #otherButton was clicked first and #button was clicked second (#button and #otherButton are on same page) it would have the same effect?

Comment: Never mind, I figured out how to do it. I created a secondClicked variable  for #otherButton, set secondClicked and firstClicked to false initially, made it so that when #button is clicked it moves on if secondClicked has been made true, and then reset both variables to false after the level has moved on so that the game can be replayed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
var nlevel = 0;

//first button
$("#button").click(function() {
    $(this).prop("disabled", true);
nlevel++;
});

//second button
$("#otherButton").click(function() {
    $(this).prop("disabled", true);
nlevel++;
if(nlevel==2)
{
nlevel = 0;
gotonlevel(); // function call for next level
}
});

function gotonlevel()
{
// code for next level 
}
```

Comment: This is the method I tried first. I'm not sure why it hasn't worked :/ Thank you though!

Comment: Definitely it works. Try it. Make sure there is no any syntax error. Try to console or alert first. Then place your next level code in function. There are different way to do same thing.

Answer (score 0):

With this, either of the buttons is clicked first, it will give you success.

```
var buttonClick = 0;
$("#button, #otherButton").on("click", function(){
  if(buttonClick == 0){
    buttonClick++;
  }else{
     console.log("Success.");
  }
});
```

Comment: This is one of the methods I tried after using the counter and .val didn't work. I don't know why this doesn't work for me; the code looks fine :/ Thank you though!

Comment: I had been searching Stack Overflow (among other websites) for answers to this question, and I came upon one thread with suggestions to use .val() to trigger an event. I've never seen .val before, so I didn't fully understand the thread, but I gave it a whirl anyway.